# how do i fetch offline messages from eJabberd

Tags: chat, offline, message, ejabberd

I am new to eJabberd, I am facing the following problem.

There are two users (A and B).

User A sent 10 messages to user B but user B is offline or not in network so he (user B) didn't get messages sent by user A.

so this is the major problem I am facing, please help me how do i resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Chetan

Answer (score 0):

You must enable mod_offline in the configuration to get [XEP-0160](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0160.html). [The ejabberd documentation covers this](http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#sec71).

Minimally:

```
modules:
    mod_offline: {}
```